# If you are reborn as a Deva, are you to interact with humans?

Tags: philosophy, samsara, love, deva

If I were to get a rebirth as a Deva, is it possible for me to interact with humans or my loved ones again? Would it be possible for me to help guide humans or is that forbidden?

Comment: If you think you can *believe* your way into a favourable rebirth, then why not believe your way to enlightenment. This is the part of Buddhsim that keeps people's illusions alive, and any answer that plays up to the question only reinforces that illusion. Buddhsim can get very weird and dark, sometimes. Not worth it, mate. Go for the biggest nugget, free yourself!

Answer (score 1):

"If I were to get a rebirth as a Deva, is it possible for me to interact with humans or my loved ones again?"

Yes!

"Would it be possible for me to help guide humans or is that forbidden?"

Yes, it would be possible to help guide humans.

Comment: are you a practicing Buddhist or a professor of religious studies? Not tryna be rude or anything you just appear as some random guy lol

Comment: I am neither a Buddhist nor a Professor. I tend more towards Taoism than Buddhism, but I respect the Buddha as the greatest human being in our history. I don't belong to any religion! I am an independent spiritual being and learn a lot from Buddhists. "Zen mind beginners mind!"

Comment: I cannot provide detailed references at the moment, as I am busy with other things.

Comment: Perhaps later on when I have more time.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some stories I've collected of devas interacting with humans
https://lucid24.org/sted/8aam/4kammanto/fortune/index.html